# How to select last number in the string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "this is test
           1. this is test
           2. this is test
              3. this is test
           this is test
           1. this test
                   2. this is test";
```

I want `2`.

Another example:

```
var str = "this is test
           1. this is test
           2. this is test
              3. this is test
           this is test
           1. this test
                   2. this is test
           this is test";
```

I want `2`.

Another example:

```
var str = "this is test
           1. this is test
           2. this is test
              3. this is test
           this is test
           1. this test
                   2. this is test

           this is test";
```

I want `null`, because two continuous `\n` breaks that sequence.

---

As you see, I want the last number which is list-style. like this:

```
{spaces in here doesn't matter}{any digit}{dot}{every thing in here til end of line}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why is the second example `null`?  The last number in that entire string (which cannot contain line breaks they way you have in the post) is `2` unless I'm missing something.  Do you want the number in the last line of the string?

Comment: @ScottKaye I edited my question.

Comment: @winhowes `/^\s*\n?\d.*$/gm` .. But it is not complete ..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this pattern

```
^[\s\S]*(?:^|\r?\n)\s+(\d+)(?![\s\S]*(\r?\n){2})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/331)

for a mandatory dot after the number use

```
^[\s\S]*(?:^|\r?\n)\s+(\d+)\.(?![\s\S]*(\r?\n){2})
```

explanation:

```
^[\s\S]*                    # from the beginning "^" consume everything
(?:^|\r?\n)                 # if not first line then followed by a newline
\s*                         # followed by white spaces
(\d+)                       # capturing group to get your number
(?!                         # a negative look-ahead
    [\s\S]*(\r?\n){2}       # anything followed by {2} new lines
)                           # end of negative look-ahead
```

Comment: Well, what returns your regex? I don't see anything

Comment: @stack, you asked for `null`! because two continuous `\n`

Comment: Ah, I got it now ..! But when I remove one of those `\n`, all of that will be select ..! But I need to get just last `2` in what is selected.

Comment: I see, *(you wrote `$0` instead of `$1` in your fiddle)*. ok, it is somehow fine .. But it has a small problem, please take a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/330), it returns `5`. But I need to that capturing group just select every digit which is in the beginning of newline and after it is a dot.

Comment: Just if you have some free time .. please pares your regex and explain what does every part of it ... tnx

Comment: @stack, expaination above

Answer (score 0):

This should be as easy as just running

```
(string.match(/[0-9]+/gm) || []).pop()
```

this searches for the number in a multiline string and takes the last one. In case no number is found it falls back to an empty array which will return `undefined` for `pop()`. Sounds like exactly what you would need

Comment: Emm, I'm not sure ..! your regex matches every numbers ..! It doesn't follow of my pattern. And what does `pop()`?